# if var is not a NaN (so it is a number) add % to it in jquery

Tags: jquery, calculator, nan

I've got some code for a calculator which I'd now like to add a % to the result if there is a result there.

The current code is

```
    var margins = num4.split(" ");
    var topMarg = GetIntOrEmpty(margins[0]),
        rightMarg = GetIntOrEmpty(margins[1]),
        bottomMarg = GetIntOrEmpty(margins[2]),
        leftMarg = GetIntOrEmpty(margins[3]);
    console.log(topMarg, rightMarg, bottomMarg, leftMarg);

    var shorthand1 = GetIntOrEmpty (topMarg);
    shorthand1 += ' %';
```

if shorthand1 is empty I want it to not add the ' %' to it and leave it blank.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to show us what is in `GetIntOrEmpty`

Comment: Where's the code for GetIntOrEmpty?

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: So, `GetIntOrEmpty` returns either a Number or a String value. That doesn't look like good design to me. Why not make it return Number exclusively by returning `NaN` instead of `''`... That's what the `NaN` value is for - to indicate cases where the result is not a valid number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (shorthand1 !== '')
    shorthand1 += '%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an `if` statement to check whether the variable is equal to an empty string *and* is not `isNaN`:

```
if (shorthand1 !== '' && !isNaN(shorthand1)) {
    shorthand1 += ' %';
}
```

Above code edited in response to comment left by [Šime Vidas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/ime-vidas), below.

References:

- [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Comment: Ah? I hadn't caught that; oops. So presumably: `shorthand1 !== ''`?

Comment: Yes. You want to use `!=` only for comparisons in which type coercion is explicitly enabled (which is - never)...

Comment: Thanks for the catch...one day I'll learn what I'm *really* doing when it comes to JavaScript... =)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing for empty, your GetIntorEmpty could return a '0' instead of empty ''.

That needs no test, as 0% is the same as 0.

**OR:**

If you had to test for a number, and that number needed to be greater than 0, then another alternative would be:

```
if(shorthand >== 1) shorthand += '%';
```

That '>== 1' will only return true on a number (greater than 0). It would return false on the string '2', for example.